# Replace column text of gridView in vb6

Tags: grid, vb6

I want to replace all the columns in a gridview having a text value of "," with blank. How do I do that?

I try to just to give string value to the particular index column:

```
GridviewName.Columns.Item(3).text=""
```

But that generates this error:

```
Error with dataType mismatch while updating field
```

Comment: You will need to do it one row at a time. (Or create a handler that formats the display of the cell contents to be blank.)